# Factoring expressions with variable exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am supposed to find the range of solutions for this inequality:

$$\frac{2^x}{2^x-8}>2$$

I write it on this form

$$\frac{-2^x+16}{2^x-8}>0$$

I begin by looking at the numerator and try to find its roots. I write:

$$-2^x=-16$$

I try to simplify to

$$2^x=16$$

But I find that $-2^x+16$ is NOT equivalent to $2^x-16$. I am used to being able to divide both side of an equation with the same number, but that doesn't seem to apply to equations with exponents?

What is the general rule behind this, and where can I learn more about it?

Comment: Hint: Let $y=2^x$.  Then you're asking when is $\frac{y}{y-8}>2$.

Comment: What do you mean by $-2^x+16$ is not equivalent to $2^x-16$?  Do you mean something about the equations $-2^x+16=0$ and $2^x-16=0$?  Those equations have the same solutions.

Comment: Additional Hint: Use logarithms instead of trying to divide both sides by something.

Comment: Why do you think that $-2^x=-16$ and $2^x=16$ don't have the same solution?

Comment: I think that the functions f(x)=-2^x+16 and f(x)=2^x-16 are not equivalent, while they have the same roots. Keep in mind that I am trying to find when the function is positive and when it is negative, in addition to its roots.

I am a bit confused, sorry. Not used to to talking about math in English, or at all, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations $2^x=16$ and $-2^x=-16$ are equivalent however the functions $f(x)=-2^x+16$ and $f(x)=2^x-16$ are not.

You can take a look at the [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iesqpyxuqg) here, they are symmetric around the $x$ axis which means that when one is *negative* the other one is *positive*.

So if you want to solve $$-2^x+16>0$$ you are solving
$$2^x<16$$
which gives $x<4$ while if you wanted to solve $2^x-16>0$ you'd get $x>4$.

Getting back to the inequality which is true when either both $-2^x+16,2^x-8$ are positive or both are negative. They are both positive when $x<4$ and $x>3$ and they are both negative when $x>4$ and $x<3$ which is impossible so the only solution is $x\in (3,4)$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: write $$\frac{2^x}{2^x-8}-2=\frac{2^x-2^{x+1}+8}{2^x-8}>0$$ and do case work
solving this we get $$3<x<4$$

Answer (score 1):

By denoting $t=2^x$ you obtain the following inequality:

$$\frac{16-t}{t-8}>0$$

You can now multiplicate both sides of inequality by $-1$:
$$\frac{t-16}{t-8}<0$$

Ranges of $t$ satisfying this inequality are the same, as ranges of $t$ satisfying this one:
$$(t-16)(t-8)<0$$
with condition $t-8\neq 0$

Resulting range is then $t\in (8,16)$, so $x\in (3,4)$.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the roots is a good idea when your inequality is in the form $f(x) > 0$, where $f$ is a **continuous** function (the definition of "continuous" is a little technical, but it means, in essence, that the graph can be drawn without lifting pencil off paper).

There is a theorem about continuous functions called the Intermediate Value Theorem, that supports this. A simple, equivalent formulation of the Intermediate Value Theorem states that, if $f(x)$ is continuous over an interval $a \le x \le b$ (or indeed the whole real line), and $f(a) < 0 < f(b)$ (or $f(b) < 0 < f(a)$), then there is a root $c$ of $f$ between $a$ and $b$.

In other words, if the graph begins on one side of the $x$-axis and ends on the other side of the $x$-axis, then it must pass through the $x$-axis somewhere in between.

How is this helpful? Well, it means that the intervals where $f(x) > 0$ must be between roots. You'll never get a dip into negative values without there being a root there too.

Of course, all of this requires $f(x)$ to be continuous. If $f(x)$ has some kind of jump, or an assymptote, then $f(x)$ can easily stop being positive and start being negative, without there being a root in between. For example, $f(x) = 1/x$.

---

In your case, we have $f(x) = \frac{2^x}{2^x - 8} - 2$. This function has one asmyptote, where $2^x - 8 = 0$, or equivalently, $x = 3$. Everywhere else it's continuous. According to your own (correct) working, this function has one root: when $2^x = 16$, or equivalently, at $x = 4$. Let's piece this together to form the solution.

For $x > 4$, the function is continuous, but the function has no roots. This means, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, it is either all positive or all negative (or else there'd be a root in between). Since $f(5) < 0$ (plug it into your calculator), we have $f(x) < 0$ for $x > 4$.

For $3 < x < 4$, the function is also continuous, and there are no roots. Similarly, it's all positive or all negative. Trying a value in this range (e.g. $f(3.5)$) yields a positive value, so $f(x) > 0$ for $3 < x < 4$.

For $x < 3$, the function is continuous and has no roots. You know the drill. Since $f(2) = -3 < 0$, the function is negative for all $x < 3$.

Finally, note that $f(4) = 0$ (as we found earlier) and $f(3)$ does not exist. This clears up all the possibilities. Thus, the only interval on which $f(x) > 0$ is $3 < x < 4$. In interval notation, $x \in (3, 4)$.

I know that this is a far wordier approach to this question than you've probably seen before, but you asked about a general rule, and the Intermediate Value Theorem is about the closest thing we have to a general rule with (mostly) continuous inequalities.